# Msacces stored query and delphi using ado error

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2007

I have prepared this query in access and it is working ok.

`SELECT Kod, Unvan, CepTel, Telefon, (SELECT Sum(Borc.Tutar)  from borc
where carikod=kod) AS BorcTutar, (SELECT Sum(Alacak.Tutar) from Alacak
where carikod=kod) AS AlacakTutar
FROM cari;`

But when want to use query in delphi i have to use serverside corsorlocation and static cursor.

Then delphi throw an exception and says "e-fail" , "invalid argument" and diffrent kind of messages when i change the cursor locations and types..

It is working wit clientside cursor but return 0 for sum()..

How to use correctly this query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have converted the "amount" fields the currency, then delphi choose correct type for them (tbcdfield beside tintegerfield)....

report is working now